# How to set a title (not a caption)for MenuBar in Vaadin

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

I'd like to have a title for my MenuBar, but I'm not finding any methods in the Vaadin API for that. Just a small text to appear on the button which triggers the dropdown (like the user's name), instead of the triangle it shows now. Thanks!

```
MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();
menu.setWidth("70px");

MenuItem home = menu.addItem("Home", FontAwesome.HOME, new Command() {
         public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {doSomething();}});
MenuItem settings = menu.addItem("Settings", FontAwesome.COGS, new Command() {
         public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {doSomething();}});
MenuItem logout = menu.addItem("Sign out", FontAwesome.SIGN_OUT, new Command() {
         public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {doSomething();}});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly what you need, but it seems to be a top-level item (without handler) with a list of sub-items, feature which is nicely covered by the [vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.menubar.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `setWidth` you will notice that all three menus (Home, Settings, Sign out) are horizontally aligned which is, I believe, not what you want. What you want to do is more something like this:

```
MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();
MenuItem rootItem = menu.addItem("User name", null);
rootItem.addItem("Home", FontAwesome.HOME, this::doSomething);
rootItem.addItem("Settings", FontAwesome.COGS, this::doSomething);
rootItem.addItem("Sign out", FontAwesome.SIGN_OUT, this::doSomething);
```